# How to find all least-square solutions

Tags: linear-regression

I was looking at numpy's [lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) to find a least squares solution of an equation system when the following occurred to me:

Given the points `(0,0), (3,4), (4,3)`, if I regress a line through them I get `m = 0.906, c = 0.255`.

Looking at [this graph of the solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linear%20fit%20%7B0,0%7D,%7B3,4%7D,%7B4,3%7D), since my 3 points are symmetric to the `x=y` axis, there must be at least one more solution (namely my line from above mirrored on that axis). It seems to me that these two are all solutions.

How can I, in general, enumerate *all* least-square solutions?

And how is this done efficiently in numerical libraries?

Comment: Heck, `mathoverflow` is not `math.stackexchange.com`. How can I move my question over there?

Comment: standard least squares solutions are not symmetric wrt switching x and y. They minimize the summed vertical squared distances to the line. Your solution is unique.

Comment: You can flag for moderators with the request. Personally I would ask this question on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com (Perhaps think about it and then flag for moderators with the respective request.)

Comment: @guest You are right, I got confused and was unknowingly trying to to Total Least Squares / Deming regression, but used normal linear regression methods.